# GLSL linker error(Sampler needs to be a uniform (global or parameter to main))

Tags: opengl, glsl

we have  a GLSL fragment shader  :
but the problem is in this code

```
vec4 TFSelection(StrVolumeColorMap volumeColorMap , vec4 textureCoordinate)
{
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(0.0);

    if(volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[0].numberOfBits == 0)
    {       
        return texture(volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[0].TransferFunctionID,textureCoordinate.x);         
    }

    if(textureCoordinate.x == 0)
        return finalColor;

    float deNormalize = textureCoordinate.x *65535/*255*/;

    for(int i = 0; i < volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions.length(); i++)
    {
        int NormFactor = volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[i].startBit + volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[i].numberOfBits;

        float minval = CalculatePower(2, volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[i].startBit);
        if(deNormalize >= minval)
        {
            float maxval = CalculatePower(2, NormFactor);
            if(deNormalize <maxval)
            {

                //float tempPower = CalculatePower(2 , NormFactor);
                float coord = deNormalize /maxval/*tempPower*/;
                return texture(volumeColorMap.TransferFunctions[i].TransferFunctionID,coord);
            }
        }
    }

    return finalColor;
}
```

when we compile and link shader this message logs:

> Sampler needs to be a uniform (global or parameter to main), need to
>   inline function or resolve conditional expression

with a simple change like maybe the shader link successfully like changing

```
float `coord = deNormalize /maxval
```

to

```
 float coord = deNormalize  .`
```

**driver:nvidia 320.49**

Comment: in my opinion it is only a driver bug .all sampler of glsl are uniform variable .also chnaging unrelated code removes linker error!

Comment: also I mention all samplers are uniform variable

Comment: with uisng #pragma optionNV unroll all roblem soved